# How can I be sure I'm working in the correct Python version with pyenv?

Tags: python, pyenv

I setup my `pyenv` by followign the steps on [this](https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2017/08/03/installing-multiple-versions-of-python-on-your-mac-using-homebrew/) page.

`pyenv` versions gives me this:

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.8
  3.4.3
  3.5.0
  3.6.3
  3.6.4
* 3.7.2 (set by /Users/me/PycharmProjects/ConfigureDsNet/.python-version)
```

I assume that the current active Python version in `pyenv` is `3.7.2`.

If I now do `python -V` I see this:

```
Python 3.4.3
```

How can I be certain which version I'm working with?

Comment: It doesn't matter what environment you are working on. Once you type Python -V and and whatever the version you see as an output, actually this is the version you are in.

Comment: So if I want to use `3.7.2` I believe I should use command `pyenv 3.7.2` but when I type that, then `python -V` it remains at `3.4.3`.

Comment: You can set the global version with this command: pyenv global 3.7.2

Comment: No luck with that. It's still showing as `3.4.3`.

Comment: Ok. Just add eval "$(pyenv init -)" in the ~/.bash_profile and then check back again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Neeraj Kumar pointed out, adding `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` in the `~/.bash_profile` resolved the issue.